# Error 406 Not Acceptable with idHTTP on Delphi

Tags: php, xml, delphi, upload, http-status-code-406

I'm stucked with one problem here.

I need to upload data from Delphi App (or service) to web site using PHP scripts. I tried the **IdHTTP.Post** method but always receive **HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable** response. I really don't know if is a *server-side* error or *client-side* error.

The Delphi code I'm trying is:

```
procedure TMain_UploadTest.btTryPostClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    PostData.AddFile('file', 'simple.xml', 'application/xml');
    idhttp1.Post('http://' + edServer.Text + '/quick_import.php', PostData)
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and PHP script are this:

```
<?php
//quick_import.php
sleep(3);
$output = '';

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) &&  $_FILES['file']['name'] != '')
{
 $valid_extension = array('xml');
 $file_data = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
 $file_extension = end($file_data);
 if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension))
 {

  $file_name = "uploads/xmlfile" . date("YmdHis") . ".xml";

  $inp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
  $outp = fopen($file_name, "w");

  while (!feof($inp)) {
    $buffer = fread($inp, 8192);
    fwrite($outp, $buffer);
  }

  fclose($inp);
  fclose($outp);
 }
}
?>
```

but always receive **HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable** response when at **online servers**.

My *localhost* version works perfectly!

My last chance are uploading files via FTP and call PHP scripts after that, but I'm not happy with this solution... already tried **Host Support Chat** many times, but without success!

Anyone can help me how to workaround this HTTP 406 error?

Any method are accepted!

**Delphi client** and **PHP server** are the only pre-requisite of this job.

Thanks in advance!

---

I've already tried all of these line code, alone, combined etc... no success!

```
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
//IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding := 'multipart/form-data';



idhttp1.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';

IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
//IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptCharset := 'UTF-8';
IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptEncoding:= '*';//'*';

idhttp1.Request.AcceptCharset := 'iso-8859-1';
IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0';
```

between

```
    PostData.AddFile('file', 'simple.xml', 'application/xml');
```

and

```
    idhttp1.Post('http://' + edServer.Text + '/quick_import.php', PostData)
```

the `IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders.Text` of working **localhost** server are:

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------100617210443541
>
> Content-Length: 1273
>
> Host: 192.168.15.11
>
> Accept: text/html, */*
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

the `IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Text` of working **localhost** server are:

> Date: Sat, 07 Oct 2017 00:04:40 GMT
>
> Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.45 mod_ssl/2.2.29
>
> OpenSSL/0.9.8zg
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
>
> Content-Length: 582
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type: text/html

and finally the `IdHTTP1.Response.RawHeaders.Text` of **online server** are:

> Server: nginx/1.12.1
>
> Date: Sat, 07 Oct 2017 00:07:32 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
>
> Content-Length: 226
>
> Connection: keep-alive

the `IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders.Text` of **online server** with all modifiers code above **comented** are:

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------100617211049477
>
> Content-Length: 1273
>
> Host: www.hostgatorserver.com.br
>
> Accept: text/html, */*
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

when use:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
idhttp1.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptEncoding:= '*';//'*';
```

the `IdHTTP1.Request.RawHeaders.Text` of **online server** are:

> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------100617211635196
>
> Content-Length: 1273
>
> Host: online.hostgatorserver.com.br
>
> Accept: text/html
>
> Accept-Encoding: *
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

tried

```
idhttp1.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
```

but without success!

Comment: I'm at Hostgator server too...

Comment: Nice, so the answer there has a decent chance of working for you (eg explicitly setting `AcceptEncoding`)

Comment: The problem in the asked question indicated as duplicate are in Android App. The author said then Windows version are working... I tried all suggestions of answers but without success... can help me?